# SQL Substring Subquery Taking Too Long

Tags: sql, sql-server, return, substring, numeric

My current subquery is taking :26 secs to run. I'm using the following query as a subquery as part of another code which altogether takes 2 mins and 25 secs for one month a data to return.

Is there a faster query for this? The current procedureID contains alpha and numeric characters. I only want to pull the ProcedureID's beginning with numeric characters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ProcedureID
FROM Transactions
WHERE Substring(ProcedureID,1,1) NOT LIKE '[A-z]%'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to use substring here. You can just do `WHERE ProcedureID NOT LIKE '[A-z]%'`. It will check if the first character is a letter, and ignore the rest. Also, make sure ProcedureID is indexed!

Comment: Use a positive check. Negative conditions take more time.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax of the `LIKE` pattern.

Comment: Your real problem is that you are wrapping a column in a function. This means the entire table needs processed and indexes can't be used. Robbie's comment above should solve your problem as long as you have an index on ProcedureID.

Comment: @RobbieToyota! Thanks! That brought it down to :01 for the entire code. I really appreciate it. Simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

Run the query with the Execution Plan turned on. That should identify any indexes that may help. In addition if you add a new column that is 1 char long with it being populated with the first char of the ProcedureID and add an index to that column you should get better performance when querying based on that column as opposed to the substring() query you have used.

Answer (score 2):

First, the issue is unlikely to be the `substring()`.  The performance hog is the `select distinct`.

You *can* simplify the logic.  Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProcedureID
FROM Transactions
WHERE ProcedureID < 'A' or ProcedureID >= '{'  -- 'z' + 1
```

or:

```
WHERE ProcedureId >= '0' AND ProcedureId < ':'  -- '9' + 1
```

The magic characacters `'{'` and `':'` are simply the ASCII values of the characters that follow "z" and "9".  They could be replaced by an expression such as `CHR(ASCII('9') + 1)` if you prefer.

However, this will probably have minimal affect on performance.  An index on `Transactions(ProcedureID)` would help, because it covers the query/subquery.

If you really want help on the larger query, you should ask *another* question and provide the query that you really want optimized (or perhaps a representative simpler version).

EDIT:

You might actually find that a version like this is much faster with the right indexes:

```
SELECT p.ProcedureId
FROM Procedures p
WHERE p.ProcedureId >= '0' AND p.ProcedureId < ':' AND  -- '9' + 1
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Transactions t WHERE t.ProcedureId = p.ProcedureId);
```

This assumes that you have a table of which `ProcedureId` is the primary key.

Then, for performance, you want an index on `Transactions(ProcedureId)`.

Comment: Would this be simpler: `WHERE ProcedureID not between 'A' and 'z'`

Comment: @RobbieToyota . . . No.  `'za'` would meet that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    WHERE IsNumeric(Substring(ProcedureID, 1, 1)) = 1

If you do this often enough, it might be worth creating a calculated column that contains just the first character of ProcedureID.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are using a REGEXP not a like

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  ProcedureID
  FROM Transactions
  WHERE Substring(ProcedureID,1,1) NOT REGEXP  '^[A-z]'
```